# How specific do you need to be when targeting classes with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I have a simple `each()` that isn't working and in the past what I've found is that sometimes an element is nested too deeply and you need to be more specific. I am trying to find out if depending on certain levels you need divs or other identifiers?

My goal here is to eventually go through every element with the `shortpoint-list-item-subtitle` and `shortpoint-listitem-title` class and replace the ISO formatted dates with readable dates via Moment.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( window ).load(function() {
    $('.shortpoint-listitem-subtitle').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var value=currentElement.val();
    console.log(value);     
});
});
</script>
```

From what I can tell there's nothing about the code that shouldn't work. However like I said `.shortpoint-listitem-subtitle` may be nested too deeply. The value of `value` is not being logged in the console.

This is what the selector looks like using Chrome

```
#shortpoint-gt-3-i-3 > div > div > div.sp-type-file-list-item.sp-attr-connect.shortpoint-dynamic.shortpoint-dynamic-loaded.sp-meta-allow-content.shortpoint-child.shortpoint-dynamic-block.shortpoint-listitem.shortpoint-dynamic-514 > div > div.shortpoint-listitem-content > div.shortpoint-listitem-description
```

Underlying HTML

https://pastebin.com/ZkXRHNB1

```
<script type="text/javascript">


var timeout = null;
function waitForDom () {
  console.log("Checking DOM...");
  // check for the elements you expect to exist
  if ($(".shortpoint-listitem-subtitle").length) {
    $(".shortpoint-tab-title").click(function() {waitForDom();});
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    formatDates();
  }
  else {
    // adjust timeout time to whatever feels appropriate to you
    timeout = setTimeout(waitForDom, 500);
  }
}

waitForDom();

function formatDates() {
$('.shortpoint-listitem-subtitle, .shortpoint-listitem-description').each(function() {
  var currentElement = $(this);
  var value=currentElement.text();
  var dateParseRegex = /\d\d\d\d[-]\d\d[-]\d\d[T]\d\d[:]\d\d:\d\d[.]\d{7}[Z]/g;
  var formattedDate = value.replace(dateParseRegex, function (match) {
    return moment(match).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
  });
  currentElement.text(formattedDate);  
});
}

setTimeout(function () {
  var content = '';
  $(".content").append(content);
}, 2300);
</script>
```

Comment: Nesting is irrelevant to your selector as it's global to the DOM. It will look for that element *everywhere*. If it isn't working there must be another underlying problem. Are the elements being added dynamically through an AJAX request, for example?

Comment: The problem is not with your selector, the problem is with your HTML. `.shortpoint-listitem-subtitle` is a div element. Div elements do not have a `.val()`. They have `.text()`, which you would need to parse out the actual date text from the label text in your function. The other (and I think best) option, is to wrap your actual date in a `span` and give that a specific class, target that class, and replace the entirety of the text.

Comment: Also note that `load()` as an event handler is deprecated. You should be using `.on('load', fn)` instead.

Comment: Oh, that's funny, I was using window load() because I thought document ready was deprecated. Haha, thanks for the heads up, I'll get that changed over.

Comment: They're different entities, with different purposes. If you want the logic to execute after all images and CSS has been loaded, use `$(window).on('load', fn)`, otherwise use a standard document.ready event handler.

Comment: Ideally I'd like the code to run -after- the other code in the page renders the content in the HTML that is pulled from the REST query. So for that is document.ready fine?

Comment: Unfortunately no - and that is your issue which I mentioned above; loading content via AJAX. As that request is asynchronous it takes *much* longer for the content to be generated, and hence you're searching the DOM long before those elements exist. You need to place your logic in the callback function of that request to your REST service. If you could add that relevant code to the question we can give you an example of how to do that

Comment: The request to the REST service is made via a connection in the interface of this program...just for reference the application is SharePoint, I'm trialing a design add-in that lets you place design elements in a page and connect your data to them. For example, I can insert a "Simple List" and instead of manually adding items I dynamically fill it with a connection to a REST service where I pass in a SharePoint search query. This is all done in the interface, I'm not putting code in any back-end pages. So I'm not sure where I could do a callback?

Comment: "Callback" doesn't mean a server side call.  *"I dynamically fill it with a connection to a REST service"* - so you have some javascript that makes a call and then takes the response of that call to update your html - that update is the callback - add your datefix() method to the code that updates the html.

Comment: @freedomn-m I would assume if that was true/accessable, the OP could just format the value before inserting it into the HTML, rather than after-the-fact. I think it may be more complex than a regular AJAX call/response

Comment: There is no javascript I'm putting into a page, it might look like javascript or code after the page is already run but on my end and on the server end, there is no user intervention into the pages. This is SharePoint so pages are rendered using master pages. This add-in circumvents that, in the interface you select "REST API" (from a list of choices on where you want your data from), you paste in your REST URL, and you click "Connect". When the page loads in a client browser is when the call is made. However like I said this is all done in/by the product, not by any code I'm inserting per se.

Comment: @mhodges You're right, in the past I've modified date values in display templates that get a "current context"(native functionality) of a search result list. The display template is what is used to render each search result item. I've definitely pre-formatted date fields here. But this is slightly different.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce How often can the data be updated? Is it only on the page load, or is it triggered by user input?

Comment: @mhodges it's on page load

Comment: @ChristopherBruce Okay, that's not so bad. It's not the best practice, but you can loop and check the DOM until the elements exist. I will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with your selector, or some "max-depth" limit of DOM traversal (which doesn't exist, by the way), the problem is with your HTML. `.shortpoint-listitem-subtitle` is a div element. Div elements do not have a `.val()`. They have `.text()`, which (currently) you would need to parse out the actual date text from the label text in your function. The other (and I think best) option, is to wrap your actual date in a `span` and give that a specific class, target that class, and replace the entirety of the text.

#### Using `String.prototype.replace()` with a regex pattern to replace the date:

```js
$('.shortpoint-listitem-subtitle, .shortpoint-listitem-description').each(function() {
  var currentElement = $(this);
  var value=currentElement.text();
  var dateParseRegex = /\d\d\d\d[-]\d\d[-]\d\d[T]\d\d[:]\d\d:\d\d[.]\d{7}[Z]/g;
  var formattedDate = value.replace(dateParseRegex, function (match) {
    return moment(match).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
  });
  currentElement.text(formattedDate);  
  console.log("Old Value: ", value);
  console.log("New Value: ", formattedDate);
  console.log("\n");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="shortpoint-listitem-subtitle" style="color: rgb(163, 180, 156);">Created by: Joe on 2018-02-01T19:20:46.0000000Z</div>
<div class="shortpoint-listitem-description">Last Modified: 2018-02-08T21:14:25.0000000Z by Tom</div>
```

#### Using a `<span>` to hold the contents of each date:

```js
$('.date').each(function() {
  var currentElement = $(this);
  var value=currentElement.text();
  var formattedDate = moment(value).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
  currentElement.text(formattedDate);  
  console.log("Old Value: ", value);
  console.log("New Value: ", formattedDate);
  console.log("\n");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="shortpoint-listitem-subtitle" style="color: rgb(163, 180, 156);">Created by: Joe on <span class="date">2018-02-01T19:20:46.0000000Z</span></div>
<div class="shortpoint-listitem-description">Last Modified: <span class="date">2018-02-08T21:14:25.0000000Z</span> by Tom</div>
```

To deal with the uncontrollable asynchronicity of the content loading on your page, you can loop on a timeout until your elements exist, at which time you can format the dates and exit the timeout loop, like so:

```js
var timeout = null;
function waitForDom () {
  console.log("Checking DOM...");
  // check for the elements you expect to exist
  if ($(".date").length) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    formatDates();
  }
  else {
    // adjust timeout time to whatever feels appropriate to you
    timeout = setTimeout(waitForDom, 500);
  }
}

waitForDom();

function formatDates() {
  $('.date').each(function() {
    var currentElement = $(this);
    var value=currentElement.text();
    var formattedDate = moment(value).format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    currentElement.text(formattedDate);  
    console.log("Old Value: ", value);
    console.log("New Value: ", formattedDate);
    console.log("\n");
  });
}

// use event delegation to register click handlers on dynamically created elements
$(document).on("click", ".shortpoint-tab-title", function () {
  waitForDom();
});

setTimeout(function () {
  var content = '<div class="shortpoint-listitem-subtitle" style="color: rgb(163, 180, 156);">Created by: Joe on <span class="date">2018-02-01T19:20:46.0000000Z</span></div><div class="shortpoint-listitem-description">Last Modified: <span class="date">2018-02-08T21:14:25.0000000Z</span> by Tom</div>';
  $(".content").append(content);
}, 2300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: Nice, this is looking good so far. It was definitely an asynchronous issue as you suggested. I haven't quite implemented the date format replacing yet however I wanted to tackle something else real quick, hopefully this should be pretty easy. I might have misspoken a bit earlier when I said "on page load only". On the page there are tabs that when the user clicks makes a call to the REST service, so should I just attach waitForDom() to onClick of the tabs? Because as it is now, the code doesn't run for anything EXCEPT the tabs that are active on page load.

Comment: @ChristopherBruce Correct, attach it to the onClick handler for the tabs.

Comment: So I'm kind of stuck on the best way to replace the text, normally if this was C# I would use regex to get a match from a string and assign it to a new variable  and then just replace the text in the original string using the regex with the new formatted date. I feel like this should be easy but googling "jquery extract date from string" isn't showing relevant results. Is there an easier way to do this? For starters my regex to match an ISO I think should be \d\d\d\d[-]\d\d[-]\d\d[T]\d\d[:]\d\d:\d\d[.]\d{7}[Z] for dates formatted like 2017-07-14T16:19:06.0000000Z

Comment: @ChristopherBruce JavaScript supports [Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). A handy tool I use for testing is [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/). Just be sure that JavaScript is selected on the left panel - I believe the default is PHP

Comment: @ChristopherBruce JavaScript's [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) also supports replacing regular expressions, like so: `myStr.replace(/myregex/g, function (match) { return moment(match).format("my date format"); });`

Comment: So does that code actually replace the text / values of what end users see? In your first method that is, not the <span> method. The text and the divs are already on the page so if I insert divs and spans in the each method I'm going to end up with a bunch of duplicate stuff on my page, I'd rather just replace text if I can.

Comment: Also, in the interim I worked up a solution for replacing the text however whenever I click on a tab I get a "Cannot read property '1' of null" so I'm wondering if I attached the function correctly to the click, see my updated question. (edit: I just realized with your code I could do both DOMs at once with a comma lol)

Comment: Okay yes your code does so an in place update, so it's much more elegant than my solution.

Comment: okay so actually everything works but here's the kicker, the way I attached waitForDom() (which is right before clearTimeout(timeout)), if I click on a tab, it renders the list with the ISO date format but if I click the tab again it will re-load with the proper date format. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: @ChristopherBruce Can you update your question with the code you have currently? I want to see how you attached `waitForDom` to the click handler. I also would like to see your `waitForDom()` function as you have implemented it with your selectors

Comment: Okay, just added it

Comment: @ChristopherBruce I don't see the click handler, can you add that as well?

Comment: It's right under if ($(".shortpoint-listitem-subtitle").length)

Comment: @ChristopherBruce Ah, it's in the wrong spot. I have updated my post - take a look.

Comment: Hey bud. Your solution works but I wanted to pose another question to you. I received an answer to my support ticket about modifying the time values via jQuery and they said I can list to a jQuery event like "Shortpoint-init[Name]" where [Name] is a name of a widget I'm using. So my question to you is, how can I take the code and replace the waitForDom with a jQuery event listener to do the same thing?

Comment: @ChristopherBruce Ahh, that is called [namespacing events](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/). That would *definitely* be the way to go

Comment: Can you give an example in your answer?